# How to Avoid update operation when user changed the Picklist value manually

Tags: apex, trigger

I have standard Picklist field `currency` on Lead object. I  have a trigger,  which checks when **countrycode='86'** then it will set the currency as **'CNY'** otherwise set it to **'USD'.**

Now my requirement is that when user try to manually change the picklist field value which dosn't match with `countrycode` then **no update** operation performed.

My code logic is:

```
 if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate)
 {
       for (Lead lead :(List<Lead>)trigger.new)
               {
                  if(lead!=null &&  lead.Country_Code__c=='86')
                   {
                   Lead l=new Lead();
                   l.CurrencyIsoCode='CNY';

               }
                 else

                 {
                   Lead l=new Lead();
                   lead.CurrencyIsoCode='USD';
                 }    
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you typecasting `trigger.new` to `List<Lead>`? FYI, `trigger.new` will hold the list of sObject records, in your case I assume it is Lead, therefore, you don't need to explicitly typecast it.

Comment: Second, which trigger event are you using? Before or After? Do you mind sharing entire trigger code?

Comment: @Mahmood if you use one of the trigger context collections (new, old, newmap, oldmap) outside of a trigger (i.e. in a separate apex class), then you have to cast the collection. At compile time, the type of `Trigger.new` is only `List<MyObject>` inside of a trigger on `MyObject`. Everywhere else, the type is `List<sObject>`. If you don't cast it, you'll get a compilation error saying that `Loop variable must of of type sObject`

Comment: I totally agree Derek, but OP mentioned trigger in the question, not helper class or something similar. In case of trigger its not required.

Answer (score 0):

A simple validation rule would be sufficient...

```
ISCHANGED(CurrencyIsoCode) && 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(CurrencyIsoCode, "CNY")) &&
Country_Code__c == "86"
```

This validation rule will check to see if the currency field is being changed to something other than "CNY" when the Country Code is 86 and allow you to error the update. You could also accomplish this in your trigger but a simple validation rule will be more maintainable in the future.